# Racket Pass List Elements to a Function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to pass the values that I have within a list to a function.

Ex:

```
(define l (list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3 4))) --> l = '((1) (2) (3 4))

(define (myFunc el1 el2 el3)
    ...Whatever is in my function).
```

Thus, how would I be able to call myFunc with the elements in l, 
I would have `(myFunc '(1) '(2) '(3 4))`.

Comment: `(apply myFunc l)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply`. For instance:

```
(define l (list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3 4)))

(define (my-func el1 el2 el3)
  (+ (length el1) (length el2) (length el3)))

(apply my-func l)   ; => 4
```

[Here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) is the documentation.

Comment: Awesome thanks! One more question though. What if I wanted to pass my list values to a macro, how would I be able to do that? Ex : (define-syntax myMacro (syntax-rules () (myMacro <expr> ...)))